# How to get root url of my application

Tags: php

I want to print the root URL of my application folder . like `localhost/metro/`, here metro is my folder where I am working.

No matter which directory I am currently in it will print out the `localhost/metro/`

I have tried this

```
<li class=""><a href="<?php $server = $_SERVER['HOST'] .'/metro';echo $server;?>" target="_self" class="">Home</a></li>
```

But doesn't work, Actually I want to build a navigation menu, by which can I always navigate to the place I want, no matter which place I am currently in.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

```
<?php
    $rootUrl = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
?>

<li class=""><a href="<?php echo $rootUrl; ?>" target="_self" class="">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php  $Url = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].substr(__DIR__, strlen($_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ])); ?>

<a href="<?php echo $Url .'/';?>" target="_self" class="">Home</a>
```